# How do I fix this html error for a slideshow?

Tags: javascript, html

I am pretty new to html so I really don't know what to do. I want to create an image slideshow but I get this error in the browsers console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'style')

I didn't try anything because I don't know what I possibly could try.

```js
const slideshowImages = document.querySelectorAll('#slideshow img');
let currentIndex = 0;

function showNextImage() {
  slideshowImages[currentIndex].style.display = 'none';
  currentIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % slideshowImages.length;
  slideshowImages[currentIndex].style.display = 'block';
}

// console.log(slideshowImages);
setInterval(showNextImage, 5000);
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: scroll;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  font-family: 'Milkshake', Arial, sans-serif;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 3.5em;
  margin-top: 1px;
}

p {
  margin: 20px 0;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 20px 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header {
  overflow: hidden;
}

li {
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.content {
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
  padding: 20px 1px;
}

img {
  width: 90vw;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

#slideshow {
  position: relative;
}

#slideshow img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 400px;
  left: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

#menu {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 2;
}

#menu ul {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#menu li {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
}

#menu a {
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 20px;
}

#menu a:hover {
  background-color: #444;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Bildgallerie</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Kontakt</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Datenschutz</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Impressum</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<header>
  <img id="image" src="https://i.imgur.com/CcAmnTw.jpg" alt="Foto">
  <div id="slideshow">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/okK0XWD.jpg" alt="Slideshow image 1">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/Nq4gaBP.png" alt="Slideshow image 2">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/q9UR9DM.png" alt="Slideshow image 3">
  </div>
</header>

<div class="content">
  <h1>ParadisoPiccolo</h1>
  <h2>Location</h2>
  <p>Our apartment is located in the heart of the city</p>
  <h2>Features</h2>
  <ul>
    <li>2 bedrooms</li>
    <li>1 bathroom</li>
    <li>Fully equipped kitchen</li>
    <li>Spacious living room</li>
    <li>Balcony with city view</li>
  </ul>
  <h2>Rates</h2>
  <p>Daily rate: $100</p>
  <p>Weekly rate: $700</p>
  <p>Monthly rate: $2500</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Well, it means that whatever you're trying to find the style property for doesn't exist. I'd guess that your index is out of range.

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour], then simplify the demo above to just what's needed for your question. I'd bet we don't need to see the menu or features list.

Comment: Do you know how to use your browser to debug JavaScript? If not, you should look into that. Set a breakpoint on the faulty line(s) and see if the values are what you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your  tags are above your actual HTML, For some reason The Javascript is parsed and executed first, before the HTML actually renders any elements with those ids and tag types... so just put your script tags under the body like so:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>ParadisoPiccolo</title>
    <style>
    body {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: scroll;
    }
    h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    font-family: 'Milkshake', Arial, sans-serif;
    }
    h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 3.5em;
    margin-top: 1px;
    }
    p {
    margin: 20px 0;
    line-height: 1.5;
    }
    ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 20px 0;
    padding: 0;
    }
    header {
    overflow: hidden;
    }
    li {
    margin: 10px 0;
    }
    .content {
    position: relative; 
    top: 1px; 
    padding: 20px 1px;
    }
    img {
    width: 90vw;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: block;
    vertical-align: top;
    }
    
    #slideshow {
    position: relative;
    }
    
    #slideshow img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 400px;
    left: 400px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    }

    #menu {
    position: fixed;  
    width: 100%;  
    background-color: #333;  
    color: #fff;  
    z-index: 2;  
    }

    #menu ul {
    display: flex;  
    margin: 0;  
    padding: 0;  
    }

    #menu li {
    flex: 1;  
    text-align: center;  
    }

    #menu a {
    display: block;  
    color: #fff; 
    text-decoration: none; 
    padding: 20px;  
    }

    #menu a:hover {
    background-color: #444;
    }

    </style>

    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="menu">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Bildgallerie</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Kontakt</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Datenschutz</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Impressum</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
  
    <header>
    <img id="image" src="https://i.imgur.com/CcAmnTw.jpg" alt="Foto">
    <div id="slideshow">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/okK0XWD.jpg" alt="Slideshow image 1">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/Nq4gaBP.png" alt="Slideshow image 2">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/q9UR9DM.png" alt="Slideshow image 3">
    </div>
    </header>
 
    <div class="content">
    <h1>ParadisoPiccolo</h1>
    <h2>Location</h2>
    <p>Our apartment is located in the heart of the city</p>
    <h2>Features</h2>
    <ul>
    <li>2 bedrooms</li>
    <li>1 bathroom</li>
    <li>Fully equipped kitchen</li>
    <li>Spacious living room</li>
    <li>Balcony with city view</li>
    </ul>
    <h2>Rates</h2>
    <p>Daily rate: $100</p>
    <p>Weekly rate: $700</p>
    <p>Monthly rate: $2500</p>
    </div>
    </body>
    
        <script>
    const slideshowImages = document.querySelectorAll('#slideshow img');
    let currentIndex = 0;

    function showNextImage() {
    console.log(slideshowImages[currentIndex]);
    slideshowImages[currentIndex].style.display = 'none';
    currentIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % slideshowImages.length;
    slideshowImages[currentIndex].style.display = 'block';
    }
    console.log(slideshowImages);
    setInterval(showNextImage, 5000);

    </script>
    
    </html>
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I want to slideshow to appear somewhere (I can change the position later on by myself) ontop of that sunset image. But somehow it doesn't work. Can you tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

First, please replace your javascript code block just before body close tag in order to fix your Uncaught TypeError.

And currently, your slide show doesn't appear on the page.

So next, update your css related to slideshow.

The whole working code as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>ParadisoPiccolo</title>
    <style>
        body {
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            overflow: scroll;
        }

        h1,
        h2,
        h3,
        h4,
        h5,
        h6 {
            font-family: 'Milkshake', Arial, sans-serif;
        }

        h1 {
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 3.5em;
            margin-top: 1px;
        }

        p {
            margin: 20px 0;
            line-height: 1.5;
        }

        ul {
            list-style: none;
            margin: 20px 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        header {
            overflow: hidden;
            position: relative;
        }

        li {
            margin: 10px 0;
        }

        .content {
            position: relative;
            top: 1px;
            padding: 20px 1px;
        }

        img {
            width: 90vw;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            display: block;
            vertical-align: top;
        }

        #slideshow {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 300px;
            height: 300px;
        }

        #slideshow img {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            object-fit: cover;
        }

        #menu {
            position: fixed;
            width: 100%;
            background-color: #333;
            color: #fff;
            z-index: 2;
        }

        #menu ul {
            display: flex;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        #menu li {
            flex: 1;
            text-align: center;
        }

        #menu a {
            display: block;
            color: #fff;
            text-decoration: none;
            padding: 20px;
        }

        #menu a:hover {
            background-color: #444;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Bildgallerie</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Kontakt</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Datenschutz</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Impressum</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <header>
        <img id="image" src="https://i.imgur.com/CcAmnTw.jpg" alt="Foto">
        <div id="slideshow">
            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/okK0XWD.jpg" alt="Slideshow image 1" style="display: block">
            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/Nq4gaBP.png" alt="Slideshow image 2" style="display: none">
            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/q9UR9DM.png" alt="Slideshow image 3" style="display: none">
        </div>
    </header>

    <div class="content">
        <h1>ParadisoPiccolo</h1>
        <h2>Location</h2>
        <p>Our apartment is located in the heart of the city</p>
        <h2>Features</h2>
        <ul>
            <li>2 bedrooms</li>
            <li>1 bathroom</li>
            <li>Fully equipped kitchen</li>
            <li>Spacious living room</li>
            <li>Balcony with city view</li>
        </ul>
        <h2>Rates</h2>
        <p>Daily rate: $100</p>
        <p>Weekly rate: $700</p>
        <p>Monthly rate: $2500</p>
    </div>


    <script>
        const slideshowImages = document.querySelectorAll('#slideshow img');
        let currentIndex = 0;

        function showNextImage() {
            slideshowImages[currentIndex].style.display = 'none';
            currentIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % slideshowImages.length;
            slideshowImages[currentIndex].style.display = 'block';
        }
        console.log(slideshowImages);
        setInterval(showNextImage, 5000);

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I want to slideshow to appear somewhere (I can change the position later on by myself) ontop of that sunset image. But somehow it doesn't work. Can you tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: For that, please update your css as follows:         header {
            overflow: hidden;
            position: relative;
        }
        #slideshow {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 300px;
            height: 300px;
        }

        #slideshow img {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            object-fit: cover;
        }

Comment: And I updated my above solution for that.

Comment: You can customize the position of the slideshow by editing the top and left values of #slideshow.

Comment: If you are satisfied with my answer can you give a green check mark to my answer?